# How works casting from an object to a String variable in VB?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I've made some code to go back to an overview page of a blog section of a site. The variables `OverviewLink1` and `OverviewLink2` in code below are both `HtmlAnchor`s and would set the `Href` properties equal to the variable `state` I've made.

The property `HttpContext.Current.Application` gets the `System.Web.HttpApplicationState` object for the current HTTP request.

```vb
Dim state As HttpApplicationState = HttpContext.Current.Application(component.type & "-" & webId & "-" & langId)
OverviewLink1.HRef = state ' <-- Error happens on this line
OverviewLink2.HRef = HttpContext.Current.Application(component.type & "-" & webId & "-" & langId)
```

This code gives an error on the second line:

> Value of type `HttpApplicationState` cannot be converted to `String`.

The third line don't give an error. [Try it here in this fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/deU9N0) Now I've got some questions:

1. How is this possible that the third line works?
2. How casting works in VB to a variable in general?
3. How to prevent this situation? Because I'm coming from C# and this situation isn't possible.

I'm using VB with an ASP.NET webform *(the CMS is Liquifi)* application.

**P.S.:** The variables `component.type`, `webId` and `langId` are variables used by the CMS Liquifi to get respectively the name of the component *(type of `String`)*, the ID of the website *(one website could have multiple skins)* *(type of `Integer`)* and the language of the site *(type of `Integer`)*

**Update:**

I've tried also this code

```vb
Dim state As String = HttpContext.Current.Application(component.type & "-" & webId & "-" & langId)
OverviewLink1.HRef = state
OverviewLink2.HRef = state
```

and this works fine however `HttpContext.Current.Application` returns a `HttpApplicationState` and not a string but there is a cast happen. Why?

Comment: Are you sure that the 3rd line works?

Comment: @Pikoh: yeah I'm sure see the fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/deU9N0

Comment: That fiddle does not say anything, because `HttpContext.Current` is `Nothing`, so the type returned is not `HttpAplicationState`

Comment: @Pikoh: this is just an example. Inside my application it works fine. BTW it doesn't matter what the result of `HttpContext.Current.Application(component.type & "-" & webId & "-" & langId)` is because the compiles didn't know when a `null` _(`Nothing` for VB)_ will be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that in VB.NET, flexible autoconversion of types is turned on by default, which can bring very unexpected results and runtime errors. Especially if you came from strict language like C#.

I would recommend everyone to turn this autoshit off on every project by setting:
**Project Properties -> Compile -> Option Strict On**

Now it will cry every time you will try to assign something to something else which is not compatible.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is you think `HttpContext.Current.Application` returns a `HttpApplicationState`. That's right if you don't give it any parameter, but if you pass a parameter it returns an **`Object`** (the item that match that key).

In C# your code's third line wouldn't compile as it does a strict type checking,but in VB.net (by default) it doesn't,so it compiles and in runtime would try to convert that `Object` to a `String`. Your example is similar to this code:

```
Dim s As Object = "A"
'Both of the next two lines compiles
Dim str As String = s   ' it works
Dim str2 As Integer = s ' Would fail in runtime
```

If you cast `HttpContext.Current.Application(key)` to an `Object`, it would also compile:

```
Dim state As HttpApplicationState = HttpContext.Current.Application(component.type & "-" & webId & "-" & langId)
Dim state2 As Object = HttpContext.Current.Application("blog-1-1")
Dim str3 as String= state 'Compile error, you can't convert HttpApplicationState to String
Dim str4 as String = state2 'It compiles, would give a runtime error
```

You would solve this problems using the [`Option Strict`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/311329/option-explicit-and-option-strict-in-visual-basic-.net-and-in-visual-b) flag. That way your 3rd line wouldn't compile, as VB.NET would do strict type checking as C# does.